# How do I recover the contents of a file overtaken by Location List?

Tags: vim

I was editing a file, db.go. After making some changes that resulted in a syntax error, the window contents suddenly got replaced by a [Location List] window (see attached image).

I quickly typed some commands (from muscle memory) that I normally type to undo or go back, but somehow I ended up overwriting my local file with the contents of  the [Location List] window and I can't find a way to go back to the file to press "u" and recover the file contents. If I try to open "db.go" in another Vim window in the same session, I get the same "[Location List]" window.

If I press Ctrl+o I get error:

Error detected while processing function GoFormat:
E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off.

I use vim-go, which may or may not have something to do with this (but they do talk about quickfix and location list in the install docs).

How can I close the [Location List] window in a way that when I try to edit db.go, I see the file contents instead of the location list window?[image]

Comment: You can see the buffers Vim knows about with `:ls` and you can switch to one of them with `:b N` (where N is the number of the buffer), you can use `:b! N` if the current buffer needs to be dropped (might work around the `'modifiable'` issue, though possibly not.) Consider using [vi.se] for questions on Vim!

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that and it didn't work. It would still show the [Location List] contents. I ended up reopening Vim and rewriting the code I lost.